# iOS iPhone how to list all keywords in a UTextView by frequency of use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview, keyword

I got a `UITextView` with an arbitrary length text (up to 10000 characters). I need to parse this text, extract all keywords and list them by the frequency of use with the most frequently used word being on top, next one down, etc. I will most likely present a modal UITableView after the operation is completed.

I'm thinking of an **efficient and useful** way to do this. I can try to separate a string using a delimiter in the form of [whitespace, punctuation marks, etc].
 This gets me an array of character sequences.
 I can add each add sequence as an `NSMutableDictionary` key, and increment its count once I see another instance of that word. However, this may result in a list of 300-400 words, most having frequency of 1.

Is there a good way to implement the logic that I'm describing? Should I try to sort the array in alphabetical order and try some kind of "fuzzy" logic match? **Are there any NSDataDetector or NSString methods that can do this kind of work for me?**

An additional question is: how would I extract stuff like a, at, to, for, etc, and do not list them in my keyword list?

It would be great if I can take a look at a sample project that has already accomplished this task.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not clear on something. You want to list all the keywords by frequency but a lit of 300-400 words ordered by their frequency isn't good because most of them appear once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the `CFStringTokenizer` . I'm not sure if the bridged casts below are correct, but it seems to work

```
-(void)listAllKeywordsInString:(NSString*)text
    {
        if(text!=nil)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary* keywordsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1024];
            NSString* key = nil;
            NSLog(@"%@",text);

             NSLog(@"Started parsing: %@",[[NSDate date] description]);

            CFStringRef string =(__bridge CFStringRef)text; // Get string from somewhere

        CFStringTokenizerRef tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,  (__bridge_retained CFStringRef) text, CFRangeMake (0,CFStringGetLength((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)text)), kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord, CFLocaleCopyCurrent());

            unsigned tokensFound = 0; // or the desired number of tokens

            CFStringTokenizerTokenType tokenType = kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone;

            while(kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone != (tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer)) ) {
                CFRange tokenRange = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tokenizer);
                CFStringRef tokenValue = CFStringCreateWithSubstring(kCFAllocatorDefault, string, tokenRange);

                // This is the found word
                key =(__bridge NSString*)tokenValue;

                //increment its count
                NSNumber* count = [keywordsDictionary objectForKey:key];
                if(count!=nil)
                {
                     [keywordsDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:key];
                }else {
                    [keywordsDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count.intValue+1] forKey:key];
                }



                CFRelease(tokenValue);

                ++tokensFound;
            }
            NSLog(@"Ended parsing. tokens Found: %d, %@",tokensFound,[[NSDate date] description]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[keywordsDictionary description]);
            // Clean up
            CFRelease(tokenizer);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CFStringTokenizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html) to get the word boundaries. For counting, you could use an `NSMutableDictionary`, as you suggested, or an `NSCountedSet`, which might be slightly more efficient.

If you're not interested in words that have a frequency of 1 (or some other threshold), you would have to filter them out *after* counting all the words.

For ignoring certain words (a, the, for...), you need a word list specific to the language of your text. The [Wikipedia article on stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) contains a couple of links, e.g. [this CSV file](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt).

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to do this.

You should definitely add all your Keywords to an array (or other collection object) and reference it/ iterate through it so you are searching for these keywords and only these keywords (and are avoiding checking for occurrences of a, at, to, for, etc.)

```
NSArray *keywords = [ add your keywords ];

NSString *textToSearchThrough = @" your text ";  // or load your text File here

- loop control statement here (like maybe fast enumerate), and inside this loop:
NSRange range = [textToCheckThrough rangeOfString:keywords[currentKeyword] 
                              options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
   // meaning, you did find it 
   // add it to a resultsArray, add 1 to this keyword's occurrenceCounter (which you must also declare and keep track of)
   // etc.
}
```

Then you loop through your results array, check number of occurrences per keyword, purge those who's occurrence count is < minOccurrenceCount, and sort remaining from highest to lowest.